# Can't get height of dynamic created button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

## What I have:

I dynamically create a button and try to access the button width. In this example I'm doing `console.log()` but in my real case I want to use that value for other things.

```js
let deleteButton = $(document.createElement("button"))
  .addClass("deleteButton")
  .text("delete")
  .click(function() {
    delete(this);
  });

console.log($(deleteButton).width());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## The Problem:

Buttons have a `width` and `height` by default, but the `console.log()` shows zero.

**How to get the default width and height of the button?**

*Observation:* The most likely answer to be accepted is using `.width()` like functions of jquery or explain why that function is not working and show a better solution.

Comment: Can you make a pen file and share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `$.width()` gets the current ***computed*** width for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Basically, that element wasn't rendered/processed by the engine, so the `width` is not available before it's added to the DOM tree.

```js
let deleteButton = $(document.createElement("button"))
  .addClass("deleteButton")
  .text("delete")
  .click(function() {
    delete(this);
  });

// Here the engine will render/process this element.
$(document.body).append(deleteButton);

console.log($(deleteButton).width());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```